# Shrink an LVM partition to extend an ext2 partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted, lvm

I have been struggling with this problem for about 6 hours now and I've searched through multiple forums for parts of the solution. But I always seem to get stuck.

I need to extend my ext2 partition because my boot folder gets full every time I try run any sort of apt-get update and the updates fail. I have an LVM partition that is ~110GB in size that I want to shrink by 10-20GB so that I can extend my ext2 partition.

[image: See GParted Screenshot]

I am booting from GParted Live USB to reconfigure the partitions. I ran lvreduce to decrease the size of the drive (hence the 10GB free) but I cannot shrink the space IN FRONT of the LVM partition so that I can expand the ext2 partition. I tried to follow this guide (https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted) but it seems they can magically shrink in front, and I cannot.

Any help is very much appreciated. Please be patient I'm a bit of a Linux noob.

Comment: If your /boot partition gets filled up by kernel images, the easier solution could be to [remove old kernel images](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu).

Answer (score 1):

Try KDE Partition Manager 3.0. It can resize LVM. You can get it from various live cds, e.g. from KDE Neon (you still need to install KDE Partition Manager when you boot live cd).

You first need to shrink your LVM Logical volume, then shrink LVM PV at the end. Finally, move LVM PV to the right.